# gnuplot: first row of data skipped

Tags: gnuplot

Am using gnuplot 5.0. with the following as pereamble to each script:

```
set terminal epslatex 8 color standalone colortext
```

The issue is that gnuplot is skipping the first row. To my knowledge 4.6 version addressed a similar issue.

### Any idea on the problem please?

Example of data file points.dat

```
4 4
4 -4
-4 4
-4 -4
```

The first line (4, 4) is skipped. So instead of four points, only three are displayed by gnuplot. Herewith the command am using

```
#!/bin/bash


set terminal epslatex 8 color standalone colortext 
set output outputFileName

set size .55,.55
set pointsize 3.0


##############
# Line styles
##############

set linestyle 1 lt 5 lw 1 #
set linestyle 2 lt 2 lw 1.5 
set linestyle 3 lt 6 lw 1 #
set linestyle 4 lt 3 lw 1 
set linestyle 5 lt 2 lw 2 #
set linestyle 6 lt 1 lw 2


##################
# Titles
##################
set title 'Image'
set xlabel '$x$' offset 0,0.5
set ylabel '$y$' offset 2,0


set macros
filename_init = sprintf("%s/image_init.dat",dataFileDirectory)


set key autotitle columnhead
set key horiz


set multiplot
plot
     filename_init  u 1:2 with points lt 0 pt 1 lw 5 lc rgb "magenta" notitle 'initial'
```

On trick to bypass the issue is to duplicate the first row. Bu this is not practical.

Comment: Do you mean that you're plotting a curve from a data file and `gnuplot ` skips the first data point?  Would you mind posting an example, consisting of a short data file and the minimum set of `gnuplot` commands that trigger the unwanted behavior? Thank you in advance

Comment: The command `plot 'points.dat' using 1:2 w l` plots all four points, i.e. three lines. Maybe some are just hidden behind the borders. Using `set offsets 1,1,1,1; plot 'points.dat' using 1:2 w l` I get the plot  http://i.stack.imgur.com/kLzj9.png with 5.0, which is correct.

Comment: It is not a problem of borders. I had similar issues with prior versions of gnuplot. The previous version, 4.6, solved the issue, which is now showing up with the new version. Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Works fine both with `qt` and your `epslatex` terminal settings.

Comment: Sorry, am ploting with points not lines. @Christoph, does it work for you when using points?

Comment: Yes, works fine as well. My test script: `reset; set terminal epslatex 8 color standalone colortext; set output 'foobar.tex'; set multiplot; set offsets 1,1,1,1; plot 'points.dat' u 1:2 w points lt 0 pt 1 lc rgb "#008000" notitle; unset multiplot; set output`. Then I compile with `latex foobar.tex`, `dvips foobar.dvi`, `ps2pdf foobar.ps`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70312/discussion-between-polar-and-christoph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `set key autotitle columnheader` gnuplot uses the entries in the first row as key entries, even though for the plot you have specified `notitle`.

To demonstrate this, consider the following script, using the four data points in `points.dat`, which you posted:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'foobar.png'

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key autotitle columnhead

filename_init = 'points.dat'

set multiplot layout 1,2
plot filename_init u 1:2 with points lt 0 pt 1 lw 5 lc rgb "magenta"

set key noautotitle
plot filename_init u 1:2 with points lt 0 pt 1 lw 5 lc rgb "magenta" title 'initial'
unset multiplot
```

The result is

[image]

So, just remove the line `set key autotitle columnhead` from your script, and use `plot ... title 'initial'`. That gives you the expected result.