# Why gnuplot omits first data line?

Tags: gnuplot

I wrote the following "tmp.dat" datafile

```
\# 0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20
\#inFile;cn;mv;nr;nd;nn;fil;sep;m#enn=;m#enn=;n=;i=;aLea1=;rLea1=;amea1=;rmea1=;NbaLea1=;NbrLea1=;Nbamea1=;Nbrmea1=;rrmen3a1=
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;0;?;?;?;?;0.0110485435;0.0078125;14;11.1540828402;4225;0;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00172
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;1;0.0165088727;1745;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;42;11.2126074499;1745;1;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00172
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;2;0.0165088858;1726;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;35;11.2027809965;1726;2;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00272
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;3;0.0165088801;1724;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;39;11.214037123;1724;3;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00372
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;4;0.0165088766;1720;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;34;11.1831395349;1720;4;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00472
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;5;0.0165088776;1718;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;32;11.1850989523;1718;5;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00204;0.00572
ex32new_DMLPG_beta3_der1emeno5/fort.501;6;0.0165088822;1710;64;0;0.0441941738;0.0078125;34;11.216374269;1710;6;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00205;0.00898;0.00158;0.00205;0.00205;0.00672
```

My gnuplot script

```
set datafile separator ";"
set datafile missing "?"

set grid

set xlabel "coarsening level"

set ylabel "rrmen3a1"

set xrange [-1:7]
set yrange [*:*]

set terminal pdf color
set output "tmp.pdf"

plot \
"tmp.dat" using 2:21 index 0 with lp title columnheader(1), \

#    EOF
```

does NOT plot the "first" point (0,  0.00172), only points x=1,...,6
Any hint?

Comment: The first line is consumed by `title columnheader`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28346228/2604213

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your plot line

```
plot "tmp.dat" using 2:21 index 0 with lp title columnheader(1)
```

This instructs gnuplot to use your first record (which does not include commented lines) to use as column labels. So your first data line is being interpreted as a header.  If you do not want to reformat your datafiles, you can plot a dummy curve with the same header file which will act as your data series label. Something like

```
plot "tmp.dat" using 2:21       index 0 with lp lt 1 lc rgb 'black' notitle, \
     "tmp.dat" using ($0):(1/0) index 0 with lp lt 1 lc rgb 'black' columnhead(1)
```

Note that we have to manually specify the line styles to ensure the keys have the same linestyle as the curves.

Comment: Thank you Gavin for your exhaustive explanation!