# GNUPLOT: First data row not shown in barchar

Tags: gnuplot

I am generating a simple barchar with a line representing average value using GNUPLOT. Everything works fine, but I have noticed that GNUPLOT is always avoiding the first data row. I can explain why because I am not very experienced in this library.

An example of data file

**file.dat**

```
#"semana" "valor"  "avg_consumo"

"Dec-16" 308893.68781 341525
"Jan-17" 335020.44772 341525
"Feb-17" 311196.136253 341525
"Mar-17" 352105.952394 341525
"Apr-17" 335570.091083 341525
"May-17" 373732.943507 341525
```

An example of the command I am executing for generating is this one

```
gnuplot -e "fuente='file.dat'; out='~/output.png'; titulo='Title';titulo_media='Average';color='#729fcf';media='18337';limite='48713.6237385';" script.sh
```

And the script is the shown below

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term postscript
set terminal pngcairo nocrop enhanced size 500,300 font "Siemens Sans,12"
set output out
unset title
set boxwidth 0.8 absolute
set border 3
set style fill solid 1.00 border lt -1
set style histogram clustered gap 1 title textcolor lt -1
set style data histograms

set xtics border scale 1,0 nomirror autojustify norangelimit
unset ytics

set key off auto columnheader
set key ins vert center top

set offset 0,0,graph 0.05,0

if(limite != 0 ){
  set yrange [0.0000 : limite] noreverse nowriteback
}else{
  set yrange [-1 : 1] noreverse nowriteback
}

set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by -45  autojustify
set ytics nomirror
set xtics  norangelimit
set xtics ()

show style line

set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb color lw 0
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb color lw 3
set style arrow 3 lt 2 lc rgb 'black' lw 4


plot fuente using (column(0)):2:xtic(1) title titulo ls 1 with boxes, '' u 3 ls 3 lw 4 lc rgb '#333333'  title titulo_media with lines
```

And the generated graph is this one, where the 'Dec-16' row is missing

[image]

Someone could help me identify what is the error in the script?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the line `set key off auto columnheader`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28348560/2604213

Comment: Thanks you so much... I would never imagine that